# Terms of Service pops up on Sign-In although already agreed

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using the [Single-Page Application built on MSAL.js with Azure AD B2C](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp) together with the [A B2C IEF Custom Policy - Sign Up and Sign In with 'Terms of Use' prompt](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-sign-up-versioned-tou) and a custom RestAPI profile to enrich the output claims.

Everything seems fine until I press the "Call API" button of the application, which prompts the "I agree to the Terms of Service" popup:

[image]

This should not be happening, as the latest ToS were agreed upon signup. The same happens if I logout and login again. So somehow aquiring the access token prompts the same popup.

I believe that this prompt should be displayed only on signin anyway (i.e. when acquiring an id token), so something is not right with my configuration.

Btw, the id token looks fine to me:

[image]

How could I fix this?

---

This is the custom policy that I am using:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="tenant.onmicrosoft.com" PolicyId="B2C_1A_TOU_SUSI" PublicPolicyUri="http://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TOU_SUSI">

  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>tenant.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice">
        <DisplayName></DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>CheckboxMultiSelect</UserInputType>
        <Restriction>
          <Enumeration Text=" I agree to the Terms Of Service" Value="AgreeToTermsOfUseConsentYes" SelectByDefault="false" />
        </Restriction>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="currentTime">
        <DisplayName>Current Time</DisplayName>
        <DataType>dateTime</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>Current date time in UTC.</AdminHelpText>
        <UserHelpText>Current date time in UTC.</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="extension_termsOfUseConsentDateTime">
        <DisplayName>Terms of Use Consent Date Time</DisplayName>
        <DataType>dateTime</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>Terms of Use Consent date time in UTC.</AdminHelpText>
        <UserHelpText>Terms of Use Consent date time in UTC.</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="termsOfUseConsentRequired">
        <DisplayName>Terms of Use Consent Required</DisplayName>
        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>Boolean that specifies if Terms of Use Consent is required or not.</AdminHelpText>
        <UserHelpText>Boolean that specifies if Terms of Use Consent is required or not</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="extension_termsOfUseConsentVersion">
        <DisplayName>Terms of Use Consent Version</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>Terms of Use Consent Version.</AdminHelpText>
        <UserHelpText>Terms of Use Consent Version.</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
    <ClaimType Id="groupIds">
        <DisplayName>Your Group Ids</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetCurrentDateTime" TransformationMethod="GetCurrentDateTime">
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="currentTime" TransformationClaimType="currentDateTime" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>

      <ClaimsTransformation Id="IsTermsOfUseConsentRequiredForDateTime" TransformationMethod="IsTermsOfUseConsentRequired">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentDateTime" TransformationClaimType="termsOfUseConsentDateTime" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="termsOfUseTextUpdateDateTime" DataType="dateTime" Value="2020-01-30T23:03:45" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="termsOfUseConsentRequired" TransformationClaimType="result" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>

      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetNewUserAgreeToTermsOfUseConsentVersion" TransformationMethod="CreateStringClaim">
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="value" DataType="string" Value="V1"/>
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentVersion" TransformationClaimType="createdClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>

    <!-- Not used here, but this OR IsTermsOfUseConsentRequiredForDateTime check can be used -->
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="IsTermsOfUseConsentRequiredForVersion" TransformationMethod="CompareClaimToValue">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentVersion" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="compareTo" DataType="string" Value="V2" />
          <InputParameter Id="operator" DataType="string" Value="not equal" />
          <InputParameter Id="ignoreCase" DataType="string" Value="true" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="termsOfUseConsentRequired" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
  </BuildingBlocks>

  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
    <!-- Page that prompts for a new TOU on sign in if the users TOU is out of date-->
      <DisplayName>Self Asserted</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Input-ToU-SignIn">
          <DisplayName>Self Asserted ToU</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
            <Item Key="AllowGenerationOfClaimsWithNullValues">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice" DefaultValue="AgreeToTermsOfUseConsentNo" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Update-TOU-Status" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>

        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="currentTime" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="termsOfUseConsentRequired"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentDateTime" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groupIds" DefaultValue="[]" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetCurrentDateTime" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Check-TOU-Status" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-GetProfile" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <!-- read the last time the user consented -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Check-TOU-Status">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentDateTime" DefaultValue="2017-10-01T15:00:00.0000000Z" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="IsTermsOfUseConsentRequiredForDateTime" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <!-- write the current time to the consent attribute if the user reconsents to TOU on sign in -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Update-TOU-Status">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="currentTime" PartnerClaimType="extension_termsOfUseConsentDateTime" />
          </PersistedClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <!-- sign up page with TOU checkbox-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmailCustom">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetCurrentDateTime" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice" DefaultValue="AgreeToTermsOfUseConsentNo" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Email" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />

            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <!-- <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" /> -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <!-- During sign up, write the current time of consent, and version -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="currentTime" PartnerClaimType="extension_termsOfUseConsentDateTime"/>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentVersion" DefaultValue="V1" />
          </PersistedClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-GetProfile">
          <DisplayName>Get user extended profile via a REST API call</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://<myserveraddress>/claims/GetGroupIds</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_RestApiUsername" />
            <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_RestApiPassword" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Claims parsed from your REST API -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groupIds" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.AzureActiveDirectoryProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId"><MyApplicationObjectId></Item>
            <Item Key="ClientId"><MyClientId></Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>

      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>

  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="B2CSignUpOrSignInWithPasswordToU" NonInteractive="false">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSignUp" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmailCustom" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <!-- Add condition to not execute this step for sign up scenario based on newUser claim -->
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>newUser</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Display Terms of Use consent page for any SignIn scenario based on termsOfUseConsentRequired claim -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <!-- Add condition to not execute this step for sign up scenario based on newUser claim -->
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>newUser</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>termsOfUseConsentRequired</Value>
              <Value>True</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ShowToUConsentPageForNewUser" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Input-ToU-SignIn" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <ClaimsExchanges>
          <ClaimsExchange Id="RESTGetProfile" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-GetProfile" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>

  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="B2CSignUpOrSignInWithPasswordToU" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentDateTime" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="currentTime" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groupIds" DefaultValue="[]" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="termsOfUseConsentRequired" />
        
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>

</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Comment: Please add the Policy also which helps to know what exactly you have modified from the policy you shared in link to check the ToS.

Comment: @RohitPrasad I've added the Policy with all my modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SM-AAD">
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="termsOfUseConsentRequired" />
          </PersistedClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

It is because this`termsOfUseConsentRequired` claim is not being evaluated when running the policy with **prompt=none** (SSO/silent token call within SPA).